# how to use a wildcard in a root call in Firebase Realtime Database rules setup

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database set up looks like this

```
workers: {
    worker1ID: {
        employerId: '-1'
        ownerId: 'asdafnb13214'
        name: Tony
        etc...
    }
},
companies: {
    company1ID: {
        ownerId: 'LPqNASKAN2342as'
        companyName: Good Company
        employeeIDs: {
            worker25Id,
            worker26Id
        }
        etc...
    }
}
```

As a company, I am trying to add an employee to my company using the workerId.
My current rules for writing to the workers basket is...

```
"rules": {
    "workers": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$worker": {
        ".write": 
            //allow write if authenticated AND
            "auth !== null &&
            //node doesn't exist OR (it exists AND the authenticated user is the worker)
            (!data.exists() || data.child('employerId').val() === auth.uid) || 
            //OR the authenticated user is the company that is trying to add the worker to their company
            (root.child('companies').child('$company').child('ownerId').val() === auth.uid)"
      }
    }
}
```

The third line of authentication is not working. I know it is an issue with using the wildcard `$company` because when i hardcoded `company1ID`, I was able to edit the `employerId` of `worker1ID`

How can I search all companies for a company whose `ownerId === auth.uid`.
If that is not possible, in my `fetch()` function i have the companyId available. Is there a way where I can send this companyID through the url similar to `?auth=${token}` so that i can just insert that into the rule.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

where is the $company defined? maybe you could define it within the worker document then you could do something like this

```
root.child('companies').child(data.child('companyId').val()).child('ownerId').val() === auth.uid
```

I don't know what just providing '$companyId' is going to do.

in this case each worker would have to have a field pointing to the company that they work for.